# A scheme is quasiseparated -- Exercise 5.1.F from Vakil's notes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, schemes

This is Exercise 5.1.F from [Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec3014public.pdf):

> **Exercise 5.1.F.** Show that a scheme is quasiseparated if and only if the intersection of any two affine open subsets is a finite union of affine open subsets, if and only if the intersection of any two quasicompact open subsets is a quasicompact open subsets.

The statements 1 $\implies$ 2 and 2 $\implies 1$ are easy to prove. I think I am missing something. Isn't statement 3 the definition of quasiseparatedness? Here is the definition right above this exercise:

> A topological space is **quasiseparated** if the intersection of any two quasicompact open sets is quasicompact.

So there is nothing to prove for statement 3, right? Thank you for your help!

Comment: See the latest version [FOAGnov1817](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf), same exercise, which removes part 3.

Comment: @MinseonShin: Thank you!